# Largest Contentful Paint element on background image

Tags: lazy-loading, google-pagespeed

I've searched Stack and couldn't find the answer so trying this out for the first time.  I have a background image as part of the page header and when running lighthouse it's blowing up the image.  Has anyone else encountered this?  You can see what i'm talking about [here](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-kypressurewashing-com/a53gjwv54j?form_factor=mobile).

I've tried moving them from a background image to a traditional slideshow with image tags so they would lazy load and they did the same thing.